# Droppable area does not move along div container (drop_receiving_element)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using "draggable_element" for dragging the items and "drop_receiving_element" as a droppable container. But my page is a bit long due to the number of images on the view.

When i drag an image from the bottom of the page and move it to the droppable area, it does not drop there and revert to the actual position. When i move the dragged image below the droppable area at some distance, it highlights the droppable area. So i think the droppable area is fixed with the window as it does not move along with the container. Here is my code.

```
<%= draggable_element "#{property.main_image.dom_id('main')}", :revert => true %>
<div id="img_<%= property.main_image.id %>" style="display: none"><%= image_tag property.main_image.image_url(600), :onload => 'RedBox.setWindowPosition()' %></div>


<div id="images_wastebin" class="wastebin">
 <p>Remove images by dragging them into the trashcan, and emptying it.</p>
 <img id="images_trashcan_empty" src="/images/gui/trashcan_empty.png" />
 <img id="images_trashcan_full" src="/images/gui/trashcan_full.png" style="display:none"></div>
<%= drop_receiving_element "images_wastebin", :accept => "droppable", :hoverclass => "wastebin-active", :before => "imagesTrashcan.addToTrash(element)" %>
```

Can anyone help me in this, Thanks